# How to plot the decision boundary of a One Class SVM?

Tags: python, matplotlib, scikit-learn

I am having some troubles to plot the results from a One-class SVM that I have programmed. I have tried different examples found on the web, but with no good results at all. I have the following small dataset where id is the identification of a sample and f1 to f9 are certain features:

```
id,f1,f2,f3,f4,f5,f6,f7,f8,f9
d1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0.045454545,0
d2,0.047619048,0,0,0.047619048,0,0.047619048,0,0.047619048,0.047619048
d3,0,0,0,0.045454545,0,0,0,0,0
d4,0,0.045454545,0,0.045454545,0,0,0,0.045454545,0.045454545
d5,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
d6,0,0.045454545,0,0,0,0,0,0.045454545,0
d7,0,0,0,0,0,0,0.045454545,0,0
d8,0,0,0,0.045454545,0,0,0,0,0
d9,0,0,0,0.045454545,0,0,0,0,0
d10,0,0,0,0.045454545,0,0,0,0,0
d11,0,0,0,0.045454545,0,0,0,0,0
d12,0.045454545,0,0,0.045454545,0.045454545,0.045454545,0,0.045454545,0
d13,0,0,0,0.045454545,0,0,0,0.045454545,0.045454545
d14,0,0,0,0.045454545,0.045454545,0,0,0,0
d15,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0.047619048,0.047619048
d16,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0.045454545,0
d17,0,0,0.045454545,0,0,0,0,0,0.045454545
d18,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
d19,0.045454545,0,0.090909091,0,0,0,0.090909091,0,0
d20,0,0,0,0.090909091,0,0,0.045454545,0.045454545,0.045454545
d21,0,0,0.045454545,0.045454545,0,0.045454545,0.045454545,0,0
d22,0,0.090909091,0,0,0,0.045454545,0,0,0.045454545
d23,0,0.047619048,0,0.047619048,0,0,0,0.047619048,0.095238095
d24,0,0,0,0,0,0.045454545,0.045454545,0.045454545,0
d25,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0.043478261,0
d26,0,0,0,0,0.043478261,0,0.043478261,0.043478261,0
d27,0.043478261,0,0,0.043478261,0,0,0.043478261,0.043478261,0
```

My code is the following:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn.svm import OneClassSVM
from sklearn import preprocessing

    listDrop=['id']
    df1=df.drop(listDrop,axis="columns")
    colNames=list(df1.columns.values)
    min_max_scaler=preprocessing.MinMaxScaler()
    x_scaled=min_max_scaler.fit_transform(df1)
    df1[colNames]=x_scaled
    svm = OneClassSVM(kernel='rbf', nu=0.2, gamma=1e-04)
    svm.fit(df1)
    pred=svm.predict(df1)

    listA=[i+1 for i,x in enumerate(pred) if x == -1]
    listB=[i+1 for i,x in enumerate(pred) if x == 1]
    xx, yy = np.meshgrid(np.linspace(-5, 5, 1), np.linspace(-5, 5, 7500))
    Xpred=np.array([xx.ravel(),yy.ravel()]+ [np.repeat(0, xx.ravel().size) for _ in range(7)]).T
    
    Z = svm.decision_function(Xpred).reshape(xx.shape)    
    assert len(Z) == (len(xx) * len(yy))
    Z = np.array(Z)
    Z = Z.reshape(xx.shape)((len(xx), len(yy)))
    a = plt.contour(xx, yy, Z, levels=[0], linewidths=2, colors='darkred')
    plt.contourf(xx, yy,  Z, levels=np.linspace(Z.min(), 0, 7), cmap=plt.cm.Blues_r)
    b1 = plt.scatter(pred[:, 0], pred[:, 1],  c='red')
    b3 = plt.scatter(listB[:,0], listB[:, 1], c="green")
    plt.legend([a.collections[0],b1,b3],
       ["learned frontier", "test","outliers"],
       loc="lower right",
       prop=matplotlib.font_manager.FontProperties(size=11))
```

I would like to get a plot like the following:

[image]

I found this code on the web, and I was playing with the following lines:

```
Xpred=np.array([xx.ravel(),yy.ravel()]+ [np.repeat(0, xx.ravel().size) for _ in range(7)]).T
```

This because it was throwing me an error about the dimensions, and I read that because it is a 2d plot and I have 9 features I should fill the remaining ones with any data.

Also I added the part of the assert, but I got an error:

```
 assert len(Z) == (len(xx) * len(yy))

AssertionError
```

How can I plot the results from this one class SVM, it only returns an array composed of 1 and -1 like the following:

```
[ 1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1  1 -1  1  1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1
  1 -1 -1]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The standard approach is to use [t-SNE](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.manifold.TSNE.html) to reduce the dimensionality of the data for visualization purposes. Once you have reduced the data to two dimensions you can easily replicate the visualization in the [scikit-learn tutorial](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/svm/plot_oneclass.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-svm-plot-oneclass-py), see the code below for an example.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn.svm import OneClassSVM
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
from sklearn.manifold import TSNE
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# load the data
df = pd.read_csv('data.csv')
x = df.drop(labels='id', axis=1).values

# rescale the data
x_scaled = MinMaxScaler().fit_transform(x)

# reduce the data to 2 dimensions using t-SNE
x_reduced = TSNE(n_components=2, random_state=0).fit_transform(x_scaled)

# fit the model to the reduced data
svm = OneClassSVM(kernel='rbf', nu=0.2, gamma=1e-04)
svm.fit(x_reduced)

# extract the model predictions
x_predicted = svm.predict(x_reduced)

# define the meshgrid
x_min, x_max = x_reduced[:, 0].min() - 5, x_reduced[:, 0].max() + 5
y_min, y_max = x_reduced[:, 1].min() - 5, x_reduced[:, 1].max() + 5

x_ = np.linspace(x_min, x_max, 500)
y_ = np.linspace(y_min, y_max, 500)

xx, yy = np.meshgrid(x_, y_)

# evaluate the decision function on the meshgrid
z = svm.decision_function(np.c_[xx.ravel(), yy.ravel()])
z = z.reshape(xx.shape)

# plot the decision function and the reduced data
plt.contourf(xx, yy, z, cmap=plt.cm.PuBu)
a = plt.contour(xx, yy, z, levels=[0], linewidths=2, colors='darkred')
b = plt.scatter(x_reduced[x_predicted == 1, 0], x_reduced[x_predicted == 1, 1], c='white', edgecolors='k')
c = plt.scatter(x_reduced[x_predicted == -1, 0], x_reduced[x_predicted == -1, 1], c='gold', edgecolors='k')
plt.legend([a.collections[0], b, c], ['learned frontier', 'regular observations', 'abnormal observations'], bbox_to_anchor=(1.05, 1))
plt.axis('tight')
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much @gflavia for your time in answering this question. I was thinking to use also PCA first to reduce the dimensionality of the data, but once I tested with a similar dataset and the results were not so good in a graphical way. Cheers.